# existence of quotient maps to topologically transform one shape into another

Tags: general-topology

What are the mathematical condition that are necessary for a shape A to be transformed into shape B by quotient maps ? For example , I can divide a square into two triangles by drawing a diagonal .Now if I define an equivalent relation such that every point inside one triangle is related to a point in another triangle . Then the quotient space that we obtain will be a triangle . However , I am unable to conceive of any such map which transforms a triangle into a square (or  maybe any other quadrilateral ). Similarly , by converting a cylinder into rectangle ,and then the rectangle into a triangle , and further the triangle into a cone , I can reach up to a cone from cylinder , but I cannot conceive a series of transformation for the converse. 
So , what rules govern the possibilities of quotient spaces that can arise from a given shape ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure first construction you sketched may yield a whole bunch of different topological spaces, not only a triangle.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli : Yes, I was thinking about a general situation .But , I guess
for some case you can get a triangle.Like , for the case of a square the two triangles will be congruent , so by placing them one above another , we can get a quotient map by defining a map in which points coincident on one another are related .

Comment: @G.Sassatelli : So , how to decide which conversions(realization of quotient spaces) can be made ? Can that square be converted into a pentagon , or hexagon ?

Comment: Topologically, it makes little sense to distinguish between a square, a hexagon, a circle or a triangle. They're all homeomorphic. I suspect there are uncounbtably many and unfathomably pathological topological spaces that can be realised as quotients of two triangles in a way that respects the requirement you said.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli : Could you give me a quotient mapping that brings out a pentagon from a square and a shape which the square can't be transformed into by quotient mapping ?